# How do I split a string with multiple separators in lua?

Tags: string, split, lua

I want to split a string into an array divided by multiple delimiters.

```
local delim = {",", " ", "."}
local s = "a, b c .d e , f 10, M10 , 20,5"
```

Result table should look like this:

```
{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e",  "f", "10", "M10", "20", "5"}
```

Delimiters can be white spaces, commas or dots. 
If two delimiters like a white space and comma are coming after each other, they should be collapsed, additional whitespaces should be ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code splits the string as required by building a pattern of the complement of the delimiter set.

```
local delim = {",", " ", "."}
local s = "a, b c .d e , f 10, M10 , 20,5"
local p = "[^"..table.concat(delim).."]+"
for w in s:gmatch(p) do
        print(w)
end
```

Adapt the code to save the "words" in a table.

Comment: Do closing bracket `]`, percent `%` and dash `-` allowed to be among user-defined delimiters?

Comment: I normally use this function to avoid such problems:
function escape_magic(s)
  local MAGIC_CHARS_SET = '[()%%.[^$%]*+%-?]'
  if s == nil then return end
  return (s:gsub(MAGIC_CHARS_SET,'%%%1'))
end

Comment: @tonypdmtr - Why not simply `(s:gsub("%p", "%%%0"))` ?